# How to log nginx mirror requests

Tags: linux, nginx

I have nginx server with configuration:

```
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location = /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://test_backend;
}
```

Everything works perfect, except one thing. I need to log, that mirrored request delivered. If mirrored request not delivered, I need to get some error in log file. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use another server in the middle.

```
# main server
server {
    location / {
        mirror /mirror;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location = /mirror {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:55555;
    }
}

# mirror server
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:55555;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://test_backend;
        # whatever you want to log
        access_log ....;
        error_log ....;
    }
}
```

Comment: How "location = /mirror" will be executed from "location /"?

Comment: @SergeyDi the same, as in your example.

Comment: If request will not delivered to "# mirror server", how I will know about this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

May be http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_subrequest
could help

> log_subrequest on;

Comment: Hi, please include more detail from the link in case the link die with time. Thanks!

Comment: This comment was useful for me as I wasn't really aware of log_subrequest setting. It does what it says. :) I see another line in the access logs that was made as a sub request.